# PHP problems with current url

Tags: php, explode

I use the "Current url" function to get the current link when user changing page language

```
$uri = explode('&', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$uri = $uri[0];

$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$uri : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$uri;
```

Problem is, when I have a link like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/index.php?id=shop&id2=13&lang=lt
```

`id2`, of course, disappears. What can I do about this? It is possible if `id2` is set to use *explode* with a second `&` or something like this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `$_GET` super global? If so, is there some reason you aren't wanting to use it?

Comment: @jprofitt I think that the OP is trying to remove the last GET variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) function, here is an example:

```
$uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$protocol = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$url = $protocol . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '?' . ( isset( $uri['query']) ?  $uri['query'] : '');
```

I did not see in your code where you get the script's filename, so I used `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`.

**Edit:** My mistake, I did not see that you need to manipulate / remove the last `$_GET` parameter. Here is an example on how to do that using a method similar to the above in conjunction with [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str). Note that this method will work regardless of the location of the `lang` parameter, it does not have to be the last one in the query string.

```
$protocol = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';

$params = array();
if( isset( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && !empty( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
{
    parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $params);
    $params['lang'] = 'anything';
    // unset( $params['lang']); // This will clear it from the parameters
}

// Now rebuild the new URL
$url = $protocol . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . ( !empty( $params) ? ( '?' . http_build_query( $params)) : '');
```

Thanks to @Yzmir Ramirez for an improvement in the second version that eliminates the extraneous call to `parse_url`.

Comment: I was going to use `parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` in my answer, but I like your solution with `parse_url()` better.  +1

Comment: You should edit your answer to note that your solution will work even if "lang" is not the last GET variable.

Comment: Good point @YzmirRamirez - An improvement might be to remove the call to `parse_url` and just use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$uri = explode('&', '/index.php?id=shop&id2=13&lang=lt');
$uri = $uri[0];
echo $uri; //echos /index.php?id=shop
```

You'll want to use

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

to get just the query string.  And if you want to keep all the variables, then just keep $uri set to the explode then cycle through them with a foreach.

```
$uri = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
foreach ($uri as $var_val) {
    $var_val = explode('=', $var_val);
    $var = $var_val[0];
    $val = $var_val[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://codepad.org/cEKYTAp8

```
$uri = "http://127.0.0.1/index.php?id=shop&id2=13&lang=lt";

$uri = substr($uri, 0, strrpos($uri, '&'));

var_dump($uri); // output: string(41) "http://127.0.0.1/index.php?id=shop&id2=13"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have always used, it also supports ports.

```
$protocol = (!isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) || strtolower($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) == "off") ? "http://" : "https://";
$port = ((isset($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]) &&
    // http:// protocol defaults to port 80
    (($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80" && $protocol == "http://") ||
    // https:// protocol defaults to port 443
    ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "443" && $protocol == "https://")) &&
    // Port is not in http host (port is followed by : at end of address)
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], ":") === false) ? ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : '');

return $protocol . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $port . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```