# I can't rewrite dynamic url to static

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change dynamic urls of my site to static urls for better SEO. I have tried a lot of combinations but any of them didn't work.

My url is this `index.php?page=something` and i want to convert it to `page/something`

I have tried combinations like following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-z_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

When I type in my browser mydomain/page/something returns to me my page with navbar and footer but without any content.

**Update**
That was the problem: [PHP problems with current url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116494/php-problems-with-current-url)

Comment: You might be using relative paths for `css/js/images`

Comment: i use this
$url = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$url = end($url);
maybe that is a problem...

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

#if the requested url isn't a file or a dir or an image
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$ [NC]

#process index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```